# Using serotonin for relief from allergies

Tags: human-physiology, neurotransmitter, serotonin

When someone suffers from an allergy, due some allergens they are given drugs like **anti-histamine**, **adrenaline** or **serotonin**. How does serotonin affects the body to give a relieve from the action of allergents?
What is the physiology behind this?

Comment: Welcome to the Biology commmunity. Please improve your question by citing sources of the information used (in particular, that serotonin is useful in relieving allergies).

Comment: Also, please mention in your question body what attempts you made to answer it yourself. This will enable users to post helpful answers.